# how to use NOT LIKE in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, sql-like

I have a entity as below

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {


@Id
@Column(name = "EMPSEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long empSeq;
@Column(name = "EMPID")
private String empId;
@Column(name = "WINDOWSLOGINID")
private String logInId;

// assume respective getter and setter methods
}
```

I want to query all row where logInId does not start with "5"

I tried below code:

```
query = session.createQuery("select * from Employee e where e.logInId not like 5%");
```

the above code didn't work. what is the right way to use `NOT LIKE` in `HQL`

Comment: Shouldn't the pattern (5%) in single quotes? like '5%'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your query there's an error:

```
query = session.createQuery("select * from Employee e where e.logInId not like 5%");
```

become:

```
query = session.createQuery("select * from Employee e where e.logInId not like '5%'");
```

`e.logInId` is string, so you must quote your condition 5%.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Hibernate Criteria for the same.

JPA EntityManger has unwrap() method which will return session.

```
  Session session = getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Pojo.class); 
  criteria.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.like("loginId","5%")));
  List<Pojo> list=criteria.list();
   if(null!=list && list.size()> 0){
        return list.get(0);
    }
    return null;
```